# How do I copy a list and have all items be lower case?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to copy the list current_users to a new list that converts all current items in my list to lower case. I will be using both lists to check that any items in my 'new_users' list are not in either the current_users list, or the new current_user_lower list.

```
# Make a list of five or more usernames called current_users
current_users = ['admin', 'crossbreed91', 'hadrien', 'Stefan17', 'Evie19']
current_users_2 = []
# Make another list of fiver usernames called new_users. Mas sure one or two...
# are in both lists
new_users = ['stefan17', 'evie19', 'pikachu', 'ashketchum', 'gary-oak']

# Loop through the new_users list to see if each username has already been used.
# If it has, print a message that the user will need to enter a new username.
# If it's not been used, print saying that it is available.

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f"Sorry, {new_user} is taken. please enter a different username. ")
    else:
        print(f"Good news! {new_user} is available!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `map` and `str.lower`:

```
x = map(str.lower, current_users)
for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in x:
        print(f"Sorry, {new_user} is taken. please enter a different username. ")
    else:
        print(f"Good news! {new_user} is available!")
```

Or list comprehension:

```
x = [x.lower() for x in current_users]
for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in x:
        print(f"Sorry, {new_user} is taken. please enter a different username. ")
    else:
        print(f"Good news! {new_user} is available!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .lower() in a simple list comprehension to achieve this:

```
strings = ["HELLO", "WORLD"]
lower_case_strings = [i.lower() for i in strings]

print(lower_case_strings)
```

In the case of the code you provided:

```
current_users = ['admin', 'crossbreed91', 'hadrien', 'Stefan17', 'Evie19']
current_users_2 = []

current_users = [user.lower() for user in current_users]
```